# Google Apps Script Err: Service using too much computer time for one day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that checks one number against another, and emails me if the number is too high. I have the script set to run once an hour, but in a typical day it probably fails 2/3rds of the time, returning the error, "Service using too much computer time for one day." Here it is, with details removed.

```
 function checkValue(e)
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Error Checking");

   var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("M1").getValue();
   var valueToCheckTwo = sheet.getRange("O1").getValue();


   if(valueToCheck > valueToCheckTwo)
    {
        MailApp.sendEmail("dan@XYXYXYXYXYXY.com,charlie@XYXYXYXYXYXY.com", "XYXYXYXYXYXY TITLE", "Number of Things To Attend To: " + valueToCheck+ "." + " " +

        "DOCUMENT LINK");
    }
}
```

Have I written a really inefficient script? Is there some simple way to patch this up and get it to not fail so much?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your script.  I see that you have a parameter named `e`  You don't need that for a time based trigger.  That's for something like an "On Edit" or "On Form Submit" trigger.  But that wouldn't make any difference to your situation.  You should not be getting this error for this script, and the amount of times that it is triggered.  You should search the Apps Script Issues list for the same or related issues.  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue that is related to the service provider, and not the programming language or the code editor.

Comment: Are you sure you are not exceeding the quotas? Perhaps sending too many emails or? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas    Service using too much computer time for one day. This indicates that the script exceeded the total allowable execution time for one day. It most commonly occurs for scripts that run on a trigger, which have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.

Comment: Also rather than using a trigger could you change it to a onedit function? Maybe that would help with your issue?

Comment: No good reason. It's just the first thing I would try. I would replace getActive with openById